# How to change 'Enable' property of tabcontrol from Form1 on Form2, C#, Visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tabcontrol

I have Form1 and Form2 simultaneously active, Form2 has a TabControl and I want button click event on Form1 to change 'Enable' property of tabControl on Form2

TabControl on Form2 is set to `tabControl1.enabled = false;` and Form1 acts as a login form for Form2, so I need a Login button on Form1 to enable 'tabControl1' on Form2

I can access the property by setting `private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;` to 'Public', still, using the following on button click event on Form1 doesn't do anything.

```
Form2 formnew2 = new Form2();
formnew2.tabControl1.Enabled = true;
```

Can someone please provide a simple example to help me understand or link to a previously answered question

Comment: To set the control to be public, don't change designer generated code, In your `Form2` designer, select the `tabControl1` and using property window change the `Modifier` property of your `tabControl1` to be `public`. Also make sure you are showing the instance that you made it's tab control disabled. Also if you set `tabControl1.enabled = false;` in form load event of form 2, the tabCorntrol will be disabled.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes, that's exactly what I want, `TabControl` on Form2 to be disabled by default. Note that I can enable `TabControl` with a button click event on Form2 (the button obviously resides outside `TabControl` on Form2), but my objective is to enable it from Form1. BTW, Thanks for the Tip regarding `Modifier`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I set the `Enable` property of `tabControl1` to false from property window

Comment: So I suspect that you are using the wrong reference form 2. you probably have an open form 2, but you mistakenly create an instance of form 2 again here. You should pass an instance of form 2 to form 1 and use it, also you can find your instance of form 2 using `Application.OpenForms`

Comment: @RezaAghaei  Thank you, That is exactly what it was, I was referencing a new instance instead of passing an instance from form2. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using the wrong reference of `Form2`. You probably have an open `Form2`, but you mistakenly create a new instance of `Form2` again here in your `Form1`. So changing the new instance properties has no effect on previously opened instance.

You should pass an instance of `Form2` to `Form1` and use it.

Also you can find running instance of `Form2` using `Application.OpenForms`

Answer (score 0):

In Form1 have a reference to Form2.
In Form2 wrap the TabControl's Enable property in a public method and call the it from Form1

In Form1:

```
...
        Form2 form2;
        public Form1()
        {
            // initialize and show form2
            this.form2 = new Form2();
            this.form2.Show();
        }
...
```

in Form2:

```
...
        public void EnableTabControl()
        {
            this.tabControl1.Enabled = true;
        }
...
```

then in Form1 when the button is clicked:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // verify that it was initialized
    if (form2 != null)
    {
        this.form2.EnableTabControl();
    }
}
```